# Where could I ask a question about the rules of the EuroJackpot lottery?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I saw a question on Stack Exchange where the poster seemed to be trying to generate valid EuroJackpot lottery numbers. I looked up the official rules, but they are ambiguous. I want to know if the numbers in each group can repeat, (first group is 5 numbers from 1-50. Second group is 2 numbers 1-10.)

This question doesn't seem a good fit for ANY of the Stack Exchange sites I could find. Is there a good place for this question in the Stack Exchange system?

Comment: If you can't find any sites, you can go to Area 51 and create a site proposal there.

Comment: @Devealte, thanks for the suggestion but that seems like overkill for a one-off question.

Comment: I'm just saying if you can't find any sites.

Comment: @Devealte A topic like this would likely be too narrow for a new site. Also, "there is no site that can accept this" is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks, sadly I can't edit my comment now to your suggestion.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, is that the consensus, that there's no good Stack Exchange site for this question? That was my fear. Is this Meta question considered a bad question? I've gotten downvotes for even asking it.

Comment: I can see from the ticket on the Wikipedia [EuroJackpot Lottery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurojackpot) webpage, yes.

Comment: No, this question is on-topic. I guess people are downvoting because you didn't supply more details about your intended question, so there isn't enough information to decide.

Comment: Huh. I thought my intended question was pretty straightforward: Can the 5 1-50 numbers in the EuroJackpot, or the 2 1-10 numbers, have repeats, or is each drawn number removed from the pool of available numbers before the next number is drawn? (Like would be the case with a "bingo machine" containing numbered balls that are randomly selected.

Comment: @rob, you mean the image of the ticket on that page? I don't see any repeated values on those rows of numbers.

Comment: @DuncanC - Rows: B, D & E repeat 03 & 07. --- In the Lottery ***you*** propose say the winning number is 01 02 03 04 05, the two *bonus* numbers can **not be** one through five; same for any number up to ten - but IF the winning number were 21 22 23 24 25 then any remaining number is OK - that would give you tickets that either couldn't win or numbers that couldn't be chosen, depending upon how you look at it. It **is** two separate draws, and machines. With one draw, or machine, they'd need to pull 40 balls out to make the second portion of the drawing, or simply *throw away* draws of 11 -50.

Comment: @Rob, My assumption is that the set of 5 numbers from 1-50 are drawn from one "fishbowl", and the 2 1-10 numbers are drawn from a second "fishbowl" (or machine.) Thus the examples you point out from the image don't answer the question of whether the group of 5 1-50 numbers must all be unique, or whether the 2 1-10 numbers must be unique.